# Total time in a status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

**dbo.tblHistory**

```
Id | Status | TimeStamp
-----------------------
1  | ERR    | 2017-06-20 12:00:00.000
1  | ERR    | 2017-06-20 12:15:00.000
2  | OK     | 2017-06-20 12:20:00.000
1  | ERR    | 2017-06-20 12:30:00.000
```

If the time now is 12:45. I want to return 45 mins for Id=1. i.e it's been in error state for 45 mins.

Problem is I might have table like this:

```
Id | Status | TimeStamp
-----------------------
1  | ERR    | 2017-06-20 12:00:00.000
1  | OK     | 2017-06-20 12:15:00.000
1  | ERR    | 2017-06-20 12:30:00.000
2  | OK     | 2017-06-20 12:20:00.000
```

In which case, if it is still 12:45, it's only been in error for 15 mins.

Is it possible to do this in SQL without a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem can be solved like below:

1.Find the last OK message

2.Find the next Error message from it and then get the time since then

```
select 
    DATEDIFF(mi,Min(TimeStamp),GETDATE()) as timeSinceInError 
from dbo.tblHistory 
where Id > ( select MAX(Id) from dbo.tblHistory where Status = N'OK')
```

Comment: I used a modified version of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery for getting the latest timestamp for `status='ERR'` and then do a datedifference with the current time.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,X.TimeStamp,GETDATE())
FROM( SELECT Id,Status,TimeStamp,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) RN
      FROM dbo.tblHistory
      WHERE Status='ERR' ) X
WHERE X.RN=1
```

Comment: This is so close, I now can show the time since the status for each row. Which is great but how do I know what the time it's been in error is? e.g. if it the status went `1:00 ERR, 1:15 OK, 1:30 ERR, 1:45 ERR` and it was currently `2:00` I would want it show 30 minutes in error. I don't know how to know to go back to 1:30 and not 1:00

Comment: @Stuart The above query will give you the difference between the last timestamp for `ERR` and the current time since the partition is based on status and we are filtering using `RN=1` and `status='ERR'`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

You need to get the last error timestamp and compute the difference to now.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(TimeStamp), GETDATE ())
FROM dbo.tblHistory 
WHERE Status = "ERR"
```